# Realm adding extra size to my apk

Tags: android, realm

The initial size of my apk was 2.3 MB before adding Realm library, after adding the same, the apk size increased to 10.61 MB, is it possible to reduce the size, if yes how? if not then please recommend an alternate to Realm

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use abi splits to reduce size of APK.

Normally (without splits) it includes files to support almost all architectures (ARM7, ARMv7, ARM64, x86, MIPS) This is why it's too big.

With abi splits, android studio will generate APK for each architecture, and each APK will not include files for any other architecture

Just add below section in gradle file. Also check this realm [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#how-big-is-the-realm-base-library)

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }
}
```

**Important**

Each distrubtion(APK) will only work on appropriate device. So we can say, `app-x86_64-release.apk` will not work on `armeabi-v7a` architectured device. If you try, you'll face `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]` error.

You can also check these documentations.

- [Multiple APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)
- [Configure APK Splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split)

Comment: That worked, it reduces the size significantly. One thing in my mind, if it generates apk for a single architecture, will the generated apk work for all the architectures ?

Comment: How would I then upload multiple apk's to play store ?

Comment: You need switching to advenced mode in Google Play Developer Console, it allows you upload multiple APKs, check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SimpleAndAdvanced)

Comment: From what i have read, do i have to assign a different version for each type of build generated ?

Comment: Yes that's right. Each abi split will proceed on own version group. I created a sample [gist](https://gist.github.com/blackkara/39dadcf5aa95acc015d116840ba5e66b) for you. I suggest that thinking twice before doing this process. If it's really worth then do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reduce the Apk size, but first the quickest most immediate way to do this is to remove the packages in realm  API that your application is not using or targeting. This way your apk size will decline significantly, also try compressing any resources and multimedia your app is using.
A more extreme solution is to integrate with firebase and let some of your content load into the app in real time and not on deployment.

Comment: You should tell how to "remove the packages in realm API that your application is not using or targeting"

Comment: How to remove the packages from realm ?

Comment: When using an api there are classes in the api that you target in your app, the api is divided into subdirectories that represents the packages. Open the  unzipped folder go through the packages and eliminate the once you are not usingm

Answer (score 0):

Now,you can use [AppBundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) to reduce size of APK.