# Realm application is so large

Tags: android, realm

My Realm database in android has size 20MB+. I create a simple application where I load 20 items from network and save it. Why is it my application is so large?

Just configuration:

```
Realm.init(this);
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name("database.db")
            .build());
```

Method where I load data from network:

```
public void loadMovies() {
    if (AppUtil.isNetworkConnectionAvailable()) {
        Timber.d("available");
        apiInterface.getAllMovies()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext(request -> {
                    List<Movie> movies = request.getMovies();
                    for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
                        Timber.d("movie: %s", movies.get(i).toString());
                        movieDao.addMovie(movies.get(i));
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(request -> {
                    //completed
                });
    } 
}
```

And method in dao, where I add items:

```
public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
        realm.executeTransaction(r -> r.copyToRealmOrUpdate(movie));
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The place where you are saving data is honestly more relevant than the configuration

Comment: Should I add some code where I loading data via rxJava and method where I using copyToRealmOrUpdate()?

Comment: yeah that should help

Comment: okay, I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
            .doOnNext(request -> {
                movieDao.addMovies(request.getMovies());
            })
```

and

```
public void addMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.executeTransaction(r -> r.insertOrUpdate(movies));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But it's still large. I checked the application on another device and its size was 12 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm found answer for my question:
[Realm adding extra size to my apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204648/realm-adding-extra-size-to-my-apk)

And another sites:
https://academy.realm.io/posts/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries/
https://proandroiddev.com/reducing-apk-size-by-using-abi-filters-and-apk-split-74a68a885f4e